# Check for repeat in the function callback

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Now I have implemented the following logic. There is a method that fetches all products in the cart, then by product handle, I go through the tags in each product and if there is a tag that interests me, I get this product (the desired handle is stored in the tag).

It looks like this:

```
function getDiscountedProduct(callback) {
  var cartContents = fetch('/cart.js')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => { 
      var item_handles = [];
      var items = data.items;
      for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        item_handles.push(items[i].handle)
      }

      return item_handles
    })
    .then(item_handles => {
      if (item_handles.length) {
        for (let i = 0; i < item_handles.length; i++) {
          var products = fetch(`/products/${item_handles[i]}.js`)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(product => {
            var tags = product.tags;
            if (tags.length) {
              for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                if (tags[i].includes('discount')) {
                  tags_special = tags[i].split('/');
                  var discount = tags_special[0];
                  var handle = tags_special[1];
                  var discount_percent = tags_special[2];

                  fetch(`/products/${handle}.js`)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(discounted_product => {
                      callback(discounted_product, discount_percent)
                  });
                }
              }
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
}
```

In the end, I have a callback for working with the discounted product.
It will look something like this:

```
getDiscountedProduct(function(product, discount) {
  console.log(product, discount);
})
```

But I got a problem. If there are two products in the cart that refer to the same product, then I show it twice (if they are different, then this is normal).
How and at what stage can I check the uniqueness of a discounted product?

Now I have ideas to give unique classes for each discounted product and in case it will be the same product, I will simply hide it. But it seems to me that this needs to be fixed at the algorithm stage.

Comment: Need to see some sample data in order to know how to distinguish uniqueness. You would want to use a Set or Map to track keys or combinations of keys that can be used to track which unique items have already been processed

Comment: "*How and at what stage can I check the uniqueness of a discounted product?*" - only you can know what "*products in the cart that refer to the same product*" exactly means and how you would be able to distinguish them, based on the data model, format and api that you use. In the easiest case, you could detect duplicates in the `item_handles` already.

Comment: Or is your question about the `handle = tags_special[1]`? Just put them in a `Set` and then disregard the discount if you already fetched it before.